# Fama-French 3, Carhart 4, Fama-French 5 Factor models return borderline 0% R2 (max. 6.6%). Time series regression

Tags: time-series, regression, capm, asset-pricing, fama-french

I am currently working on an industry specific time series analysis of European Equities between 201001 and 201812. I use the European Fama French factor returns (plus the momentum factor return) that have been provided by Kenneth French on his website. I set up in total 7 portfolios for my industry returns. 1 value weighted. 3 sorted by size and 3 sorted value, which are all equally weighted. I run the returns for the portfolios against the factors. in total I end up with 21 outputs, given I run all three types of models for the 7 different portfolios. Anyone an idea why the R2 are so low?

Whereas R2 is of course not the most interesting or relevant component of my or any FF model analysis, I do wonder why it is as low as I have found.

[image: R2 for the various portfolios and models]

[image]

Comment: Welcome @phk31 on Quantitative Finance SE! Could you please edit your question and provide some summary statistics for your seven portfolio returns? This seems necessary to give a detailed answer. However, did you calculate your portfolio returns in US-Dollar or local currency (because FF-factors are calculated in USD)?

Comment: I will provide them shortly. The prices and fundamental data are calculated exclusively in Euro and I only included Euro Area companies. I understand but would the variation in forex diminish the model so greatly?